# how to make listbox is resizable inside its parent?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-5.0

In a user control, I put a listbox which is bound to a dynamic datasource. This usercontrol will be in a popup window. I want to this list box can fill the rest of space of the window. Here is the Xaml I tried:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbx1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row ="0" Margin="5"
                  Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionChanged="filters_SelectionChanged">
  ......
</ComboBox>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
    <Button Content="Test" Margin="5"  Click="Button_Add" />
</StackPanel>

<DataGrid x:Name="ListGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  
  ......
</DataGrid>
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5">
  ......
</ComboBox>        
<ListBox x:Name="lstSharing" Grid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,10,0"                         
                    Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=ListGrid}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>                    
            <tkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="650" />                    
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3" Width="Auto">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" Width="120" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

What I want it height and width of list box can be setup dynamically based on windows size, the items bound to list box. But it is not working properly. Initially, the listbox has no scrollbar, I need to resize window manually so that scrollbar on display.  I can not dynamically to change with, so I put MaxWidth =600. Otherwise, it always display all item in one row.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I would try something like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstSharing" 
         Grid.Row="3"  
         Grid.Column="0" 
         Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
         Margin="0,0,10,0"                         
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>                    
            <tkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                            MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=lstSharing, Path=ActualWidth}" />                    
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

It's a little difficult to know whether this will work without seeing the parent containers, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. Have tried it. Then there is nothing on display inside listbox when run the app if applied MaxWidth binding as above.